# What will be Concurrent user count to load test? - I have Google Analytics report

Tags: performance, google-analytics, load-testing, msloadtest

I am working on Web App whose peak is only once an year. From the google analytics reports it tells like on the peak day, on peak hour, there was around 3 000 Sessions between an 2 peak hours (15 000 sessions @12:00pm & 18 000 at 13:00). User spend almost 8 minutes on the site. Every year during that time our application fails. So at what concurrency, I should test my application when I am doing load test.

Once article I read formula is this `Concurrent Visitors = Hourly visitors * Time Spent on Site / 3600` . If this is right, we need only to test till 400 users. But on Google Analytics, I saw 3800 users on its real time monitor.Is this right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

3600 is the number of seconds in an hour, so if I understand you correctly your calculation should be as follows -

```
18000 users an hour * 8 minutes * 60 seconds in a minute / 3600 = 2400
```

Which is closer to 3800.

I guess that your visitors weren't evenly distributed over one hour, that will explain the peak. If the cost difference of preparing for 4k visitors is less than the potential losses that can be caused by downtime on that critical day, I would go for it.